# Fazer uma pesquisa à base de dados sem dar refresh à página

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, modal

Eu estou a algum tempo a tentar fazer uma pesquisa à base de dados, através de um input.
A ideia é num **Model** ter um input para inserir uma data e sem usar um **submit** enviar a data para outro **Model** e ai apresentar os dados já inseridos na base de dados no outro **Model**

Até agora apenas consegui mostrar a data do 1º **Model** no 2º, tenho também já a "pesquisa" mas ela está comentada.

**HTML**

```
  <h2>Small Modal</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
  >Open Small Modal</button>
```

**No 1º Model**

```
<div class="modal-body">
        <input type="date" id="myDate" value="2000-05-05" style="font-size:20px;">         

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="teste3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal4" onclick="jstophp();teste50()">
        <a class="collapse-item">Pesquisar</a>
        </div>
```

**No 2º Model**

```
 <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-user" id="dias" name="dia" 
 placeholder="Insira o Dia" style="margin-top:2%;margin-bottom:2%;font-size:20px;">
```

**JavaScript ao Clicar no 1º Model**

```
<script>
function jstophp(){
  
 javavar=document.getElementById("myDate").value;  
document.getElementById("dias").value="<?php 
$phpvar='"+javavar+"'; 
echo $phpvar;?>";


window.history.pushState( {} , '', '?data=<?php echo $phpvar ?>' );
<?php $batata = 50; ?>

 <?php //$entradas = "SELECT * FROM calendario WHERE dia = '+javavar+'  ";
//$resultado_entradas = mysqli_query($conn, $entradas);
//while($rows_calen = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_entradas)){ ?>
//document.getElementById("teste<?php // echo $batata; ?>").innerHTML="batata";
<?php //$batata++; ?>
<?php //} ?> 
}



</script>
```

Tentei também através de URL.
Deixei embaixo tanto a tentativa que fiz ao tentar por URL e a pesquisa comentada.

Comment: se não quer dar refresh na página, faça uma chamada `ajax`

Comment: Explica melhor sua pergunta.Você quer abrir um modal que tem um input enviar o valor digitado no input para o PHP e selecionar  no banco de dados  os dados referentes a esse valor e retornar a consulta para outro modal na mesma pagina que fez a requisição?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX significa Asynchronous JavaScript e XML. Em poucas palavras, é o uso do objeto XMLHttpRequest para se comunicar com os scripts do lado do servidor.
Fazer requisições para o servidor sem recarregar a página

```js
function checkAvailability() {
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "check_availability.php",
    data:'myDate='+$("#myDate").val(),
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){
        $("#resultado").html(data);
        $("#myModalResult").modal('show');
    },
    error:function (){}
    });
}
/* ### essa função pode ser retirada porém copie o código do input e substitua esse pelo que está dentro do primeiro modal na div com id = frmCheckUsername **/
function showBtnPesquisar() {
    document.getElementById("pesquisar").innerHTML = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick="checkAvailability()">Pesquisar</button>';
}
```

```css
.m2 {
    width: 400px !important; /* aqui vc coloca a largura que deseja */
}
```

```html
<!--Bibiotecas -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- ************ Ao carregar a pagina esse titulo e o botão são carregados ****** -->
     <h2>Small Modal</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
  >Open Small Modal</button> 
 
    <!-- ************ Ao clicar no botão acima esse modal surge para escolher a data -->

     <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog m2">
             <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header">
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>X</span></button>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">
    
                    <div id="frmCheckUsername">
  <!-- Ao escolher a data a função showBtnPesquisar() faz esse input ser substituido por outro que tem a função checkAvailability() de enviar a data para o PHP. -->
                      <input name="myDate" type="date" id="myDate"  style="height:30px;" onChange="showBtnPesquisar()"> <span id="pesquisar">Selecione a data</span>  
                    </div>          
                      
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     
      <!-- Após o Ajax fazer a requisição e retornar os dados resultantes da execução do PHP, na função success:function(data) tem: -->
      <!-- $("#resultado").html(data);que vai colocar o retorno no elemento de id=resultado localizado dentro deste modal -->
      <!-- $("#myModalResult").modal('show'); que vai abrir o modal -->
    
     
        <div id="myModalResult" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
             <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header">
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>X</span></button>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">
                      
                      <span id="resultado"></span>    
                      
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

> **O caminho é esse, agora fica fácil adaptar ao que você quer**

Fica evidente que ao EXECUTAR acima, e ao selecionar uma data e clicar no botão pesquisar nada vai rolar porque aqui não executa PHP

Comment: Desculpa mas eu não percebi muito bem o exemplo que deu, no exemplo que deu mostrou uma forma de "obrigar" o utilizador a escolher a data e aparecer meio que uma forma de loading mas o meu problema é arranjar uma forma de buscar o dado da data e converter para uma variável **php** para poder fazer a pesquisa. 
Se estiver o código para transformar peço desculpa já que eu ainda estou a aprender **Javascript**

Comment: @DiogoRocha, essa obrigação de escolher uma data num determinado período é para que se possa realizar o TESTE que disponibilizei para retornar dados que estão no banco com essas datas. Na resposta não tem isso nem o LOADING.